# Passing Sprite as arguments to Constructor in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class `Item` as below

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public string itemName;
    public Sprite icon;
    public float price = 1f;

    public Item(string newItemName, Sprite newIcon, float newPrice)
    {
        this.itemName = newItemName;
        this.icon = newIcon;
        this.price = newPrice;
    }
}
```

Then, populating the List of Item during Start on different class and here's the code.

```
void Start () {
    itemList = new List<Item>();
    TextAsset asset = Resources.Load(Path.Combine("Maps", "items")) as TextAsset;
    var items = JsonHelper.FromJson<Item>(asset.text);
    Debug.Log("" + items.Length);
    for(int i= 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        itemList.Add(new Item(items[i].itemName, Resources.Load<Sprite>(items[i].icon), items[i].price));
    }
    RefreshDisplay();
}
```

And here's my `items.txt` file inside `Assets/Resources/Maps/`

```
{"Items":[{
    "id": "1",
    "itemName": "Candy",
    "price": "2",
    "icon" : "ic_candy"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "itemName": "Coin",
    "price": "10",
    "icon" : "ic_coin"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "itemName": "Bomb",
    "price": "8",
    "icon" : "ic_bomb"
  }]
}
```

I get error saying

> Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Sprite' to 'string'

at `itemList.Add(new Item(items[i].itemName, Resources.Load<Sprite>(items[i].icon), items[i].price));`

I tried sending pathname (`items[i].icon`) of sprite to the constructor but still got the error.

What can be the fix?

Comment: The only thing I see as odd is that you use the same(?) class for the Json list and itemList. That should not be possible.

Comment: @JohanLindkvist I followed that from Unity Live Training. Can you make me clear why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
Resources.Load<Sprite>(items[i].icon)
```

The icon variable from the `Item` class is `Sprite` type *but* [`Resources.Load`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) is a function that takes path which is a `string` type in its parameter. To cut this short, you are passing `Sprite` to a parameter that expects `string`.

The simple solution is to add another variable called `public string iconPath;`. You then use it to load the `Sprite` to your `public Sprite icon;` variable.

Something like below should do it:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Item
{
    public string itemName;
    public string iconPath;
    public float price = 1f;

    [System.NonSerialized]
    public Sprite icon;

    public Item(string newItemName, Sprite newIcon, float newPrice)
    {
        this.itemName = newItemName;
        this.icon = newIcon;
        this.price = newPrice;
    }
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    itemList = new List<Item>();
    TextAsset asset = Resources.Load(Path.Combine("Maps", "items")) as TextAsset;
    var items = JsonHelper.FromJson<Item>(asset.text);
    Debug.Log("" + items.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        itemList.Add(new Item(items[i].itemName, Resources.Load<Sprite>(items[i].iconPath), items[i].price));
    }
}
```

Make sure to update your Json file to accommodate the new variable name.